# cant find command ng and npm

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Why can't I run npm or ng commands?

[image]

I install `NodeJs` folder & created a `TestApp_50_Angular` project using visual stuido

folder

[image]

I am setting up env variables here

[image]

Comment: How did you install Node, and did you start a _new_ `cmd` instance before you tried using `npm`? (because any command prompt you already had open prior to installing something will _not_ automatically update its path etc. you have to close it and open a new one).

Comment: I think `node` & `angular` came installied when I installed `visual studio 2022`.  currently `npm` command only works inside `NodeJs` folder and not globally. Also `AppData\Roaming\npm` is empty folder

Comment: If you didn't install it yourself, you almost certainly don't have node.js "installed", you just have it on your drive and some things may know how to use it. Install Node properly (either from the official msi installer, or using [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)) first, and see where that gets you.